# Jetty-web.xml values not used

Tags: java, xml, configuration, jetty

I am using Jetty 9.2.9 in which I am deploying some amount of apps. Without giving here any configuration files, can you think of any reason why the jetty-web.xml is read and use in only the first app which is deployed? In the other apps in WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml is read, if it is malformed I have an exception, but the values are not applied to this web app. I am trying to override maxFormKeys and maxFormContentSize, my jetty-web.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="maxFormKeys">2000</Set>
    <Set name="maxFormContentSize">211111</Set>
</Configure>
```

I know this is hard, but since the project is massive it would be better if somebody has some overall guidelines to point me in a direction to think, instead of trying to find exact solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the documentation the jetty documentation, specifically: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-form-size.html. This section describes the different ways to set this configuration for an individual webapp vs for all webapps deployed on the server.

You should also upgrade your Jetty version to the latest version if possible, Jetty 9.2 is very old and is End-Of-Life, so this might be an issue with using that version, the current version is 9.4.28 at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already read all the documentation there is. It works fine when working with jetty-web.xml on the first app I deploy, also works fine if I want to set it for all apps in jetty.xml. Upgrading is not an option at the moment :(

Comment: Jetty 9.2.9 is subject to many security issues as well - https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security-reports.html